# signtool.exe fails after Windows 10 update and BSOD

Tags: windows-10, signtool, bsod

This is a real shot in the dark, but just wondering if anyone else has run into this problem.

After Windows 10 update to 10.0.18363.693, my system got a BSOD. Now all of the sudden signtool.exe terminates with no error message but ERRORLEVEL -1073741502.  I do have the Windows 10 SDK installed.

I read in some old post that this may mean the user account was corrupted by the BSOD.

This is not the first time that a Windows 10 update has trashed my system. I had to reinstall Windows after a Windows update about six months ago and I really don't want to go through that again.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lots of people had this problem.  Type "signtool" in the search box, click the "Newest" button.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found the workaround in the first answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60461252/visual-studio-signing-failed-signtool-exe-error/)